# Want to find matching elements from two large data list using parallel stream in java 8

Tags: java, list, performance, java-stream

I have some code where I have two API calls and I store the data in lists. I want to compare both the lists and find matching and non matching data and accordingly set the status to "YES" if it matches and "NO" if it doesn't.

Below is the code which runs perfectly if the data list is less than 1000-1500 elements. When the list has more than 2000 records it takes too long which is hitting the application performance and sometimes I get a timeout error on the server.

Below is the code where I find matching data between two lists and set the status.

`AS400data` contains data from AS400 and I am trying to compare it with `Oracledata` and set the `docStatus` to "YES" or "NO"

```
AS400Data.parallelStream()
         .forEach(x -> x.setDocStatus(Oracledata.parallelStream()
                                                .filter(o -> o.equals(x))
                                                .findFirst()
                                                .isPresent() ? "Yes" : "No"));
```

Can someone help on optimizing this piece. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.filter(predicate) .findFirst() .isPresent()` can be simplified to `.anyMatch(predicate)`. But when the predicate is an `equals` test, you should not use a Stream at all, [Mureinik’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65960741/2711488) is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Given that `AS400Data` has `n` elements and `Oracledata` has `m` elements, you're performing an O(n * m) operation, even though it's done in parallel. You can reduce this to a O(n + m) operation by converting `Oracledata` to a `Set`:

```java
Set<SomeClass> oracleDataSet = new HashSet<>(oracleData);
AS400Data.parallelStream()
         .forEach(x -> x.setDocStatus(oracleDataSet.contains(x) ? "Yes" : "No"));
```